# What is the usage of a final var in Scala

Tags: scala

What is the usage of a `final var` in Scala? What is the behavior. Are there any use cases?

(see also, [Why are `private val` and `private final val` different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412386/why-are-private-val-and-private-final-val-different), which is very close, but not the same)

Comment: I tried declaring a `private final var` and assigning it, then reassigning, it complies fine, what exactly does the final here mean?

Answer (score 9):

`final` has overloaded meanings.

It can mean "can't override in subclasses", hence `final var`.

```
apm@mara:~$ skala -Yoverride-vars
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-20130811-132927-95a4d6e987 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> trait Foo { var v = 7 }
defined trait Foo

scala> trait Bar extends Foo { override var v = 8 }
defined trait Bar

scala> trait Foo { final var v = 7 }
defined trait Foo

scala> trait Bar extends Foo { override var v = 8 }
<console>:8: error: overriding variable v in class Foo$class of type Int;
 variable v cannot override final member
       trait Bar extends Foo { override var v = 8 }
                                            ^
```

`final val i = 7` is a constant value definition (aka compile time constant) but `val i = 7` is not, irrespective of the access modifier.

This has been quoted before, but, 5.2 of the spec:

> The final modifier applies to class member definitions and to class
>   defini- tions. A final class member definition may not be overridden
>   in subclasses. A final class may not be inherited by a template. final
>   is redundant for ob- ject definitions. Members of final classes or
>   objects are implicitly also final, so the final modifier is generally
>   redundant for them, too. Note, however, that constant value
>   definitions (§4.1) do require an explicit final modifier, even if they
>   are defined in a final class or object. final may not be applied to
>   incom- plete members, and it may not be combined in one modifier list
>   with sealed.

and 4.1

> A constant value definition is of the form

```
final val x = e
```

> where e is a constant expression (§6.24). The final modifier must be
>   present and no type annotation may be given. References to the
>   constant value x are themselves treated as constant expressions; in
>   the generated code they are replaced by the def- inition’s right-hand
>   side e.

Edit: sorry, didn't notice you specifically were not asking about that.  The kids are getting ready for bed, tooth-brushing and all that, a bit distracted.

Comment: Do you know what the reason is behind constant value definitions requiring an explicit final modifier, even if they are defined in a final class or object?