# Scala inconsistence behavior for final vals with and without type ascription

Tags: scala

I am using `scala 2.10.3` and I noticed the following behavior

```
object TestConstantScala {

    final val str1 : String = "foo:" + number1
    final val number1 : Int = 123
    final val number2 : Int = 123
    final val str2 : String = "foo:" + number2

    def main(args: Array[String]){
        System.out.println(str1)
        System.out.println(str2)
    }


}
```

output:

```
foo:0  
foo:123
```

And my question is why the order makes a difference. in addition if I omit the `Int` definition it returns to behave as normal

Comment: As for the order -- it's the same behaviour as in java -- first, values are initialized to their default values (0 for int, null for reference types and so on), so at the time of initialization of `str1` initialized to 0, not to 123 (yet). What really interesting is why this behaviour is different with and without type ascriptions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are \`private val\` and \`private final val\` different?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412386/why-are-private-val-and-private-final-val-different)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the type ascription (`: Int`) `number1` doesn't even exist as a field, and therefore doesn't need to be initialized. Instead, the compiler creates an accessor method that returns the value `123` directly, and in the constructor uses the literal value `123` to initialize `str1`.

Why does it create a field when there is a type ascription? It really makes no sense in this case, but sometimes type ascription can require code that does transformations of a value, like boxing a primitive or applying an implicit conversion. These operations should only be done once, both for semantic reasons (object identity, side-effects in the implicit conversion) and for efficiency. Therefore the result must be stored in a field.

So the behavior without a type ascription is an optimization for `final` primitive fields initialized to a constant value, and the compiler isn't smart enough to apply the optimization when a type ascription is present.

Here is a more minimal example:

```
object TestConstantScala {
  final val brokenStr: String = "foo:" + brokenNumber
  final val brokenNumber: Int = 123
  final val workingStr: String = "foo:" + workingNumber
  final val workingNumber = 123

  println(brokenStr)
  println(workingStr)
}
```

And here is the output from `scalac -Xprint:constructors`, showing the AST right after moving initialization into the constructor:

```
[[syntax trees at end of              constructors]] // test18.scala
package <empty> {
  object TestConstantScala extends Object {
    final private[this] val brokenStr: String = _;
    final <stable> <accessor> def brokenStr(): String = TestConstantScala.this.brokenStr;
    final private[this] val brokenNumber: Int = _;
    final <stable> <accessor> def brokenNumber(): Int = TestConstantScala.this.brokenNumber;
    final private[this] val workingStr: String = _;
    final <stable> <accessor> def workingStr(): String = TestConstantScala.this.workingStr;
    final <stable> <accessor> def workingNumber(): Int(123) = 123;
    def <init>(): TestConstantScala.type = {
      TestConstantScala.super.<init>();
      TestConstantScala.this.brokenStr = "foo:".+(scala.Int.box(TestConstantScala.this.brokenNumber()));
      TestConstantScala.this.brokenNumber = 123;
      TestConstantScala.this.workingStr = "foo:".+(scala.Int.box(123));
      scala.this.Predef.println(TestConstantScala.this.brokenStr());
      scala.this.Predef.println(TestConstantScala.this.workingStr());
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how there is no field for `workingNumber`, only an accessor, and how in the constructor `workingStr` is initialized with `"foo:".+(scala.Int.box(123))`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues at play:

- initalization order (as @wingedsubmariner correctly mentioned)
- constant value definitions (and **not** an optimization). This is how you can get efficient pattern matches when using symbolic values, instead of literals (and Java overloads the `final` keyword the same way).

From the Scala Language Specification, Section 4.1 Value Declarations and Definitions

> A constant value definition is of the form

```
final val x = e
```

> where e is a constant expression (§6.24). The final modifier must be present and
>   no type annotation may be given. References to the constant value x are themselves
>   treated as constant expressions; in the generated code they are **replaced by the definition’s
>   right-hand side e**.