# Cannot use constant val for Named annotation

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

I am trying to inject dependencies into a play application and keep getting an error when I use an object val to reference.  Every search has said to move the val to and object and mark final but that doesn't work.  I have even tried using java interfaces with static final strings but get the same issue.

```
    class HomeController @Inject()() extends Controller {

      @Inject
      @Named(HomeController.Archive)
      var archiver: ActorRef = _

      @Inject
      @Named("aShard")
      var shards: ActorRef = _

      def sendToArchiver(msg: String) = Action {
        archiver ! msg
        Ok("thanks")
      }

      def sendToShards(msg: String) = Action {
        shards ! msg
        Ok("thanks")
      }
    }

    object HomeController {
      final val Archive: String = "archive"
    }
```

the shards value injects just fine but the archiver will not.

```
   [error] /Users/vasmith/Downloads/play-scala/app/controllers/HomeController.scala:17: annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: HomeController.Archive
   [error]   @Named(HomeController.Archive)
   [error]
```

For reference play framework - 2.5.13, scalaVersion := "2.11.8" sbt.version=0.13.13

play framwork uses guice 4.0 to implement the injections.

Resolution:
thank you som-snytt, removing the type annotation did it.  Never would have thought that would have mattered.

```
    object HomeController {
      final val Archive = "archive"
    }
```

Comment: So you did try to use `val` instead of `var` for `archiver` and `shards`?

Comment: Famously, you can't have type on it, delete `: String`. That's the convention per the spec. see constant val here http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23913239/1296806