# case object's serialization strategy

Tags: scala, serialization

Say I have a case class Declared like this:

```
case object DoubleType {
  type JvmType = Double
}
case class DoubleLiteral(value: Double) {
  type fieldType = DoubleType.JvmType
  val dt = DoubleType
  val typeWidth = 8
  //methods here after
}
```

What's scala's behaviour on serializing `DoubleLiteral(2.0)`?
Does it just serialize `value`? Or it will also serialize `fieldType`, `dt` and `typeWidth`?
If so, should I annotate `fieldType`, `dt` and `typeWidth` as `@transient`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type members like `fieldType` only exist at compile-time, they have no influence on the run-time structure of an object or its serialization. This is because of the JVM's type erasure, and applies to both type members and type parameters.

Fields like `dt` and `typewidth` are just as much a part of an instance of a case class as fields declared in the constructor like `value`. They will all be serialized. You can prevent serialization with `@transient`, but for static values like `dt` and `typewidth` it may be better to prevent them from becoming fields in the object at all. The easiest way to do this is to declare each field as a `def`. All access is done through accessor methods in Scala anyway, so there is no performance cost from this.

Comment: Could you show the assertion about private final? `scala> class Foo { private final val foo: Int = 5 ; def x = foo }` and `scala> :javap -prv Foo`? Sorry I'm too lazy ATM to try all combos of keywords.

Comment: @som-snytt That assertion was wrong, I was misremembering. I've edited in something better, but take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412386/why-are-private-val-and-private-final-val-different

Comment: Not to nit-pick impl details, but this emits a field: `class X { private final val x = 8 ; def y = x }`. The field is unused.

Comment: You're right, `javap` clearly shows a field, despite `scalac -Xprint` saying it won't create one. Maybe it's a Java interop thing?

Comment: That's interesting. What -Xprint do you mean?  I would say interop if the field were initialized.

Comment: `-Xprint:constructors` is the last one that prints a tree, and it has a `def x` but no `val` for `x`. `javap` shows that the field is never initialized. It makes no sense.