# In Scala, difference between final val and val

Tags: scala, immutability

In Scala, what is the difference between

```
val a = 1
```

and

```
final val fa = 1
```

Comment: Although that question is formulated from concurrency POV, the main answer discloses differences between val and final val.

Comment: It seems that `final val` allows the constant to be inlined into code that uses it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13412894/14955

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`final` members cannot be overridden, say, in a sub-class or trait.

Legal:

```
class A {
    val a = 1
}

class B extends A {
    override val a = 2
}
```

Illegal:

```
class A {
    final val a = 1
}

class B extends A {
    override val a = 2
}
```

You'll get an error such as this:

> :9: error: overriding value a in class A of type Int(1);
>
> value a cannot override final member

Answer (score 18):

In Scala, `final` declares that a member may not be overridden in subclasses. For example:

```
class Parent {
  val a = 1
  final val b = 2
}

class Subclass extends Parent {
  override val a = 3 // this line will compile
  override val b = 4 // this line will not compile
}
```

Also, as discussed in [Why are `private val` and `private final val` different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412386/why-are-private-val-and-private-final-val-different), if a `final val` field is holding a "constant value", a constant primitive type, access to it will be replaced with the bytecode to load that value directly.

Comment: Constant folding happens for all `final vals`, not only private, as long as their type is inferred.

Answer (score 4):

You also cannot use non-`final` `val`s in (Java) annotations.

For example, this:

```
@GameRegistry.ObjectHolder(Reference.MOD_ID)
object ModItems{
}
```

will only compile if `MOD_ID` is declared as `final`.