# What is the purpose of final val in Scala?

Tags: scala, object

As far as I could understand from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911664/in-scala-difference-between-final-val-and-valhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911664/in-scala-difference-between-final-val-and-val) the `final` keyword is to prevent overriding the member. I wrote the following:

```
object JsonSupport{
  final val someChar = '"'
}
```

It compiles, but it seems nonsensical to me. We cannot extend object. So what does that mean?