# Why when I unit test do I get coverage points with `final lazy val` but not `final val`?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, scalatest

I have some code (project source available here - https://github.com/natemurthy/testing-final-vals):

```
object Main extends App {
  final val NAME = "foo"
}
```

And I'm using ScalaTest and the SBT Coverage plugin to test this code like so:

```
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec,Matchers}

class MainTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  it should "have a name" in {
    Main.NAME shouldBe "foo"
  }
}
```

But for some reason I only get coverage points when I include a `lazy` modifier in this expression:

[image]

[image]

Why is this the case?

Comment: `val`s are already final, so you shouldn't need the `final` modifier.

Comment: @SteveChaloner: no, one can override `val` of class, so `val` is not `final` in general.

Comment: @senia I was thinking in terms of `object`s (can't override) but good point.

Comment: `final val` (without explicit return type) is a compile time constant in Scala, it doesn't exist at runtime, therefore nothing to coverage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My Guess is that the coverage tool counts executed lines.

`final val NAME = "foo"`is compiled as a constant inline value in bytecode like `private static final` in Java. When accessing the variable you just read the value from the bytecode constant. [More Info on inlining constant values during compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412386/why-are-private-val-and-private-final-val-different)

`final lazy val NAME = "foo"`on the other hand compiles into a lazy construction method since there are no lazy values in the JVM. If you access this variable the lazy construction method is executed. [More info on scala lazy value bytecode generation](http://scala-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Lazy-val-and-synchronized-td1991409.html)

Comment: @nmurthy Yes. I fixed my typo `var ` does not make sense in this context