# How is a val immutable?

Tags: scala

I know that a `val` is not `final` unless explicitly declared so and using javap confirms that Scalac is not inserting `final`into the bytecode.

So is a `val` immutable simply because the compiler stops us from writing any code that attempts to mutate it?

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13428362/1263942) on why `val`s are not `final`: they can be overriden

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`final` and immutability are two orthogonal concepts:

`val` means you can't change (mutate) a variable by assigning anything to it after initial declaration:

```
val x = 1
x = 2 // error: reassignment to val
```

In JVM bytecode it's implemented by creating a private member and a getter, but not setter:

```
class A {
  val x = 1
}

=>

// Java equivalent of a generated bytecode
public class A {
  private final int x;
  public int x() { return x; }
  ...
}
```

`final` means you can't override your `val` in a subclass:

```
class A {
  final val x = 1
}

class B extends A { 
  override val x = 2
}

// error: overriding value x in class A of type Int(1);
//  value x cannot override final member
```

`final` will cause the same error if you use `var` instead of `val`.

Comment: Unfortunately, Java conflates these uses of final so anyone coming from Java is likely to be confused at first.

Comment: @Victor, thanks for the comment. So putting my confusion of the application of `final` to one side, are you answering my question about how `val` is an immutable construct because scalac will not allow us to implement a `setter` for the `val`?

Comment: Scalac itself does not implement a setter for the val. So it is effectively immutable. Even Java's final fields can be mutated with reflection if you try hard enough.

Comment: @JamieP `val` is immutable because scalac treats it as such, technically it has nothing to do with JVM (unless you call Scala from Java). I only mentioned Java equivalent because it illustrates the concept from Java's point of view.